# Animating ItemsControl items

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, itemscontrol

I am a bit stuck as to how to approach this problem.

I have a tabcontrol on my solution and on a datatrigger I hide the tabcontrol and show an itemscontrol in its place with each item(tab) in a shape of a rectangular tile. And on selecting (simple mousedown) a 'tile' (another datatrigger ) I hide the itemscontrol and show the tabcontrol with the selected tile as the selected tab.

The above works fine without any issue. Now I am trying to see if I can animate this whole process to make it look nice visually. My goal is to make all the tiles appear nicely with a fade in effect when the itemscontrol becomes visible and then fade nice gracefully when the itemscontrol become collapsed.

My idea is to actually set all the items opacity to 0 to start with  then run a DoubleAnimation setting the opacity back to 1 on the datatrigger(giving a nice fade in effect). But I am not sure really how to approach this problem.

Can anyone help me with this one please? Sorry I havent posted any xaml but my efforts trying to animate a listbox instead, failed

Edit- Posting my efforts so far. Ideally I want it to work with an ItemsControl instead of a listbox as I dont need any interactions such as SelectedItem or anything
 please let me know if my approach itself is wrong so that I dont end up in wrong direction.

I started with a listbox and in my resources i got the below style. Please ignore my multi trigger as I had few more conditions earlier but left it like that.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter property="opacity" value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=Visibility}" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">

                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Then my listbox style

```
<ListBox  Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Visibility="{Binding ShowAnimation,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
<ListBox.Style>
    <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowAnimation}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomStyle}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Show current working code to help.

Comment: Please see my edit. But like I said it did not work for me. The animation was probably running before the listbox became visible.

Comment: You probably won't like this, but you're using the wrong tool... you should be using a custom `Panel`. In the `Panel`, you have access to each item in the collection and this is where you should be animating them. I won't lie... it's pretty complicated stuff, but it's also rewarding if you do it right. Take a look at the [Animated WPF Panels](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153554/Animated-WPF-Panels) page on CodeProject for more information. [If you search online, then you should be able to find a tutorial that is closer to your requirements.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks a lot for your idea. I think it is a brilliant one!! Like i said in my post I was probably in the wrong direction completely and wanted to know any other similar implementation. I think custom panel is a good idea. I am thinking maybe I can create a custom ItemsControl and then track Visibility changed event for the control and then animate the items inside. Do you think that would work? I really want to do it because at the moment hiding and showing works fine but I want to take advantage of WPF and show nice transitions to the user

Comment: You don't need to create a custom `ItemsControl`... you need to create a custom `Panel`. See the Custom Panel Elements section of the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) page on MSDN for a simpler (non animating) example.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. But how do I know when the parent control (itemscontrol) becomes visible and collapsed to animate the visual children? Do I need to use IsVisibleChanged event? I think I can probably use OnRender to animate when the control becomes visible. What about when it gets collapsed?